# Inheritance and model Id

Tags: database, oop

I have a `Person` class in `Contacts` subsystem. On the other hand in CRM subsystem, I have the notion of `Customer`.

In database design, I want to create a relationship between these notions. There are some possible ways:

1. Each customer *is* a person, thus customer should inherit from person and customer dies as soon as his person is removed (Composition). In this case, we create a `one-to-one` relationship between `Id` columns of the `Customers` table and `People` table, and we make the `Id` column of the `People` table an identity field, but we explicitly insert the `scope_identity()` in the `Customers` table.
2. Each customer *has* a person, thus customer and person have their own life-cycles (Aggregation) and can survive without the other. In this scenario, `Customers` table should have a foreign key to `People` table. The bad point here is that each `Person` can have many `Customers` which seems odd to me.

Which design is suggested as the best practice? I need solid objective answers. Thank you.

Comment: Don't use inheritance. Use a composite class instead.

Answer (score 1):

IHMO, every entity must have a proper ID. You write about foreign key to refer Person as Customer, but this is another concept.

If Person is a base class about Customer, so, the ID field is the same and you don't explicit in Customer class because it inherit by Person.

In the first case (Person and Customer with FK) you have:

```
class Person {
    private String id;
    ... and so on
    ... put here get and set property (as getId() / setId() and so on) 
}

class Customer {
    private String id; // this is different by id of Person class
    private Person person;
    ... and so on
    ... put here get and set property (as getId() / setId() and so on) 
}
```

In the second case (Customer extends Person) you have:

```
class Person {
    private String id;
    ... and so on
    ... put here get and set property (as getId() / setId() and so on) 
}

class Customer extends Person {
    ... other properties about Customer
    ... put here get and set property
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different cases when you may or may not give each table it's own ID.

In your case, it would be better if customer table does have it's own ID.

Example:
Own Id in a many to many relation defining table is redundant, when it doesn't have any extra column associated apart from the tables it is joining. Consider a `Teacher` and `Student` table relation. They have a many to many relation. If there is a table named `TeacherStudentRelation` having only foreign key to `Teacher` and `Student` table then it won't need any extra `OwnId` field.

But in your case, a `Customer` table surely would have extra information associated like `balance`, `purchaseList` or anything like that. And it is highly likely that you would search into `Customer` table for some data. Here an `OwnId` of customer table would let you to index that table.

Briefly, do give `Customer` table it's own Id.